# Starting with CAD on linux

Tags: software-rec, cad

I would like to do some CAD work on Linux (Fedora).

I have no experience in CAD, so I have to learn it from scratch. Do you know an CAD Tool for Linux which is easy to use? I prefer an easy tool over a fully functional, jack of all trades program.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at FreeCAD: http://www.freecadweb.org/

It is very simple to install, as it has ready-made installation packages, also for Fedora. It also has good and clear tutorials.